# htaccess reacting differently on the internet than on wamp with neither result correct

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using the following code on my `.htaccess` file which is reacting differently on wamp than it is on my server on the internet:

```
# Turn Rewrite Engine
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

# Pages 
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ page.php?title=$1 [QSA,L]

# Rewrite to www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost:7080/demo[nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.localhost:7080/demo/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

This is the code on the net for `# Rewrite to www`

```
# Rewrite to www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^biotoxinsvenomlaboratories.com[nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.biotoxinsvenomlaboratories.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

**On Wamp**

If I enter `http://localhost:7080/demo/test` (with or without a following slash) into the address bar `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ page.php?title=$1 [QSA,L]` does not recognize `.page.php` and throws a 404 error.

If I enter `http://localhost:7080/demo/page.php?title=test` it works fine.

NOTE: mod rewrite is turned on in the `php.ini` file.

**On my internet server**

Immediately a 500 error occurs. However, if I comment out `#Options +FollowSymLinks` the index page will come up if the domain is typed into the address bar.

When I enter `http://my-domain.com/test` (with or without the following slash) I get this in the address bar: `http://biotoxinsvenomlaboratories.com/testy/y/y/y/y/y/y/y/y/y/y/y/y/y/y/y/y/y/y/y/y//?q=testy&q=test` and the page says: `This webpage has a redirect loop`

I have search google and this site and have tried several recommendations (too many to list and still am at a complete loss... assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your condition will never be true because `HTTP_HOST` doesn't include the path. It is just the `HOST` which in your case would be `localhost` (not sure about port). You would want two conditions, one to check host and one to check `REQUEST_URI` which has the path.

Comment: Or you could match the URI part in the RewriteRule. `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost [nc]` `RewriteRule ^demo/(.*) ...etc...`

Comment: `^([^/]+)/?$` does not match `demo/test` (Or is your `.htaccess` located inside an actual folder named `demo`?)

Comment: the `demo` folder is on wamp... I had a virus and when I reinstalled wamp for some reason I had to go through a port so I chose `7080` as the port.